# Spark buffer holder size limit issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, amazon-emr

I am doing the aggregate function on column level like

```
df.groupby("a").agg(collect_set(b))
```

The column value is increasing beyond default size of 2gb.

Error details:

> Spark job fails with an IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow
> BufferHolder error. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow
> BufferHolder by size 95969 because the size after growing exceeds size
> limitation 2147483632

As we already known
`BufferHolder` has a maximum size of 2147483632 bytes (approximately 2 GB).
If a column value exceeds this size, Spark returns the exception.

I have removed all duplicate records, `repartition()`, increased the default partitions and did increase all memory parameters also but no use it is giving above error.
We have huge volume of data in a column after applying the agg of `collect_set`.

Is there any way to increase the `BufferHolder` maximum size of 2gb while processing?

Comment: There don't seem to be any workarounds so far, as rdd groupByKey, dataframe groupBy agg, and dataframe grouBy applyInPandas all suffer from the same issue