# Extract data into standalone file with pyspark to workaround:Spark buffer holder size limit issue

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

## Problem

I got same issue as [this one: Spark buffer holder size limit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537890/spark-buffer-holder-size-limit-issue).

My code is like :

```py
# Calculate the statistics
stats = df.groupBy("EventType").agg(
    size(collect_set("Parameters")).alias("ParameterLength"),
    collect_list("Parameters").alias("Parameters"),
    (count("*") / df.count() * 100).alias("Frequency"),
)
```

## Expect

### Solution 1

I already know most of the `Parameters` are short, only `EventType` is `A` and `B` have huge amount of parameters, Im thinking is there a way to skip `EventType` == "A" or "B" first, and output a summary table, then output `EventType` == "A" or "B" to a standalone file or something else.

What I want is something like this:

```
EventType   ParameterLength Frequency   Parameters
TimeChanged 0               0.799471    []
Alarm       40              71.643145   [ele1,ele2,...ele40]
...
A           9999999             12.12       None--> file generated
B           30031               5.21        None--> file generated
```

### Solution 2

Get top 100 of those parameters for those overflowed column like "A" and "B". Or when element > 100 , do slice, otherwise do normal.

### Solution 3

The `Parameters` array contains all many {"Key":XXX, "Value":YYY} pairs, is there a way to reduce the size by change them into tuple like (XXX, YYY) or `StructType` in spark?

Answer (score 0):

I used solution 2, and this is my code:

```py
stats = df.groupBy("EventType").agg(
    size(collect_set("Parameters")).alias("ParameterLength"),
    when(
        size(collect_set("Parameters")) > 1000,
        slice(collect_set("Parameters"), 1, 1000).alias("Parameters"),
    )
    .otherwise(collect_set("Parameters"))
    .alias("Parameters"),
    (count("*") / df.count() * 100).alias("Frequency"),
)
```